# Remove specific element from array of specifc object

Tags: javascript

I need to modify a nested array. In this example I would like to remove `content 2` from the target array of the object with the id `ZFrNsQKSY6ywSzYps`

```
var array = [
  { _id: "QKSY6ywSzYpsZFrNs", target: ["content 1"]}
  { _id: "ZFrNsQKSY6ywSzYps", target: ["content 1", "content 2"]}
  { _id: "SzYpsZFrNQKSY6yws", target: ["content 1"]}
]
```

I tried to use `find()` but with that I do not update the array. So this seems not to be the correct approach.

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: A user with your rep should know the importance of sharing effort.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to [**solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: create a a new array with filter or just splice the element out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find()` method to get object and then `indexOf()` to find element in array that you want to remove and if found `splice()` method to remove it.

```js
var array = [
  { _id: "QKSY6ywSzYpsZFrNs", target: ["content 1"]},
  { _id: "ZFrNsQKSY6ywSzYps", target: ["content 1", "content 2"]},
  { _id: "SzYpsZFrNQKSY6yws", target: ["content 1"]}
]

const obj = array.find(({_id}) => _id == 'ZFrNsQKSY6ywSzYps');

if(obj) {
  const i = obj.target.indexOf('content 2');
  if(i != -1) obj.target.splice(i, 1)
}

console.log(array)
```

Comment: I think we should just go with the duplicate question thing. You agree?

Comment: Also, this only removes it from one _id.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newarray = []
for(var i1 = 0; i1< array.length;i1++){
  var subarray = []
  for(var i2 = 0; i1<array[0].target.length;i++){
    if(array[0].target[0]!="content 2"){ // or desired removed content
      subarray.push(array[0].target[0])
    }
  }
newarray.push({"_id":array[0].id,"target":subarray})
}
```

after that simply access `newarray`

Answer (score 0):

First: elements in array should be separated by commas.

Second: Is there some logic to update target arrays? If so you can iterate over the elements and modify their targets according to that logic.

Other than that you can always do this

```
array[1].target = ["content1"]
```

Comment: Yep @TheOneWhoMade . That is exactly why I asked if there is a logic to remove "content2". If there is none this works just fine

Comment: I think we should just go with the duplicate question thing. You agree? We dont need aditional answers to a question already answered.

Comment: Sure, I'm in :))

Comment: K. Flag it as a duplicat and also edit your answer so i can retract my downvote.

Comment: I did not get it. What question should I edit?

Comment: Could you edit your **_answer_** so i can retract my downvote?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165725/discussion-between-sp3c7r00m-and-theonewhomade).

Answer (score 0):

Try tihs approach:

```
const array = [
  { _id: "QKSY6ywSzYpsZFrNs", target: ["content 1"]},
  { _id: "ZFrNsQKSY6ywSzYps", target: ["content 1", "content 2"]},
  { _id: "SzYpsZFrNQKSY6yws", target: ["content 1"]}
]

console.log(array);

array.forEach(
    item =>
        // filter out the unwanted content
        item.target = item.target.filter(
            content => content !== "content 2"
        )
)

console.log(array);
```

Comment: I think we should just go with the duplicate question thing. You agree? Instead of battling this out?

Comment: If OP wants to remove from a single object on the array, then I  agree it's a dupe, but if he needs to remove _content 2_ from all items of the array, then I think it's a question similiar, but not a duplication.

Comment: Also whats with the arrow functions?

Comment: The first one, `item => ...`, is looping through the first array, the one with the objects.

The second one, `content => ...`, is a loop inside the target item of the object, it returns the content **IF** it is different then the unwanted content.

I left out the brackets since it's a simple example, more information regarding filter function can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)